# Can't get 'fabcar' javascript docker images to run

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm on Windows and have all the prerequisites described for Hyperledger. I'm following this tutorial: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/write_first_app.html. Inside my `fabcar` folder, I ran `./startFabcirc.sh javascript` and it fails to run the docker containers. The message I get specifically is

```
Stopping for channel 'mychannel' with CLI timeout of '10' seconds and CLI delay of '3' seconds
proceeding ...
The BYFN_CA1_PRIVATE_KEY variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
The BYFN_CA2_PRIVATE_KEY variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
Removing network net_byfn
Network net_byfn not found.
Removing volume net_orderer.example.com
Volume net_orderer.example.com not found.
Removing volume net_peer0.org1.example.com
Volume net_peer0.org1.example.com not found.
Removing volume net_peer1.org1.example.com
Volume net_peer1.org1.example.com not found.
Removing volume net_peer0.org2.example.com
Volume net_peer0.org2.example.com not found.
Removing volume net_peer1.org2.example.com
Volume net_peer1.org2.example.com not found.
Removing volume net_orderer2.example.com
Volume net_orderer2.example.com not found.
Removing volume net_orderer3.example.com
Volume net_orderer3.example.com not found.
Removing volume net_orderer4.example.com
Volume net_orderer4.example.com not found.
Removing volume net_orderer5.example.com
Volume net_orderer5.example.com not found.
Removing volume net_peer0.org3.example.com
Volume net_peer0.org3.example.com not found.
Removing volume net_peer1.org3.example.com
Volume net_peer1.org3.example.com not found.
---- No containers available for deletion ----
---- No images available for deletion ----

Starting for channel 'mychannel' with CLI timeout of '10' seconds and CLI delay of '3' seconds and using database 'couchdb'
proceeding ...
LOCAL_VERSION=1.4.2
DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION=1.4.2
/d/hyperledger/fabric-samples/bin/cryptogen

##########################################################
##### Generate certificates using cryptogen tool #########
##########################################################
+ cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml
org1.example.com
org2.example.com
+ res=0
+ set +x

/d/hyperledger/fabric-samples/bin/configtxgen
##########################################################
#########  Generating Orderer Genesis block ##############
##########################################################
CONSENSUS_TYPE=solo
+ '[' solo == solo ']'
+ configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis -channelID byfn-sys-channel -outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block
2019-08-20 17:28:45.838 EDT [common.tools.configtxgen] main -> INFO 001 Loading configuration
2019-08-20 17:28:45.839 EDT [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] Load -> PANI 002 Error reading configuration:  Unsupported Config Type ""
2019-08-20 17:28:45.839 EDT [common.tools.configtxgen] func1 -> PANI 003 Error reading configuration:  Unsupported Config Type ""
panic: Error reading configuration:  Unsupported Config Type "" [recovered]
        panic: Error reading configuration:  Unsupported Config Type ""

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/zapcore.(*CheckedEntry).Write(0xc0000ebc30, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /w/workspace/fabric-release-jobs-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/zapcore/entry.go:229 +0x51c
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap.(*SugaredLogger).log(0xc000006248, 0xc000091804, 0xc00002cfc0, 0x38, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /w/workspace/fabric-release-jobs-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/sugar.go:234 +0xfd
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap.(*SugaredLogger).Panicf(0xc000006248, 0xc00002cfc0, 0x38, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /w/workspace/fabric-release-jobs-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/sugar.go:159 +0x80
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/flogging.(*FabricLogger).Panic(0xc000006250, 0xc000091908, 0x1, 0x1)
        /w/workspace/fabric-release-jobs-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/flogging/zap.go:73 +0x7c
main.main.func1()
        /w/workspace/fabric-release-jobs-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/tools/configtxgen/main.go:260 +0x1b0
panic(0xa3c760, 0xc000183490)
        /opt/go/go1.11.5.linux.amd64/src/runtime/panic.go:513 +0x1c7
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/zapcore.(*CheckedEntry).Write(0xc0000ebc30, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /w/workspace/fabric-release-jobs-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/zapcore/entry.go:229 +0x51c
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap.(*SugaredLogger).log(0xc000006228, 0xc000091c04, 0xc00002cec0, 0x38, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /w/workspace/fabric-release-jobs-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/sugar.go:234 +0xfd
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap.(*SugaredLogger).Panicf(0xc000006228, 0xc00002cec0, 0x38, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /w/workspace/fabric-release-jobs-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/sugar.go:159 +0x80
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/flogging.(*FabricLogger).Panic(0xc000006230, 0xc000091d88, 0x2, 0x2)
        /w/workspace/fabric-release-jobs-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/flogging/zap.go:73 +0x7c
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/tools/configtxgen/localconfig.Load(0xc0000304a0, 0x15, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc0004224d0)
        /w/workspace/fabric-release-jobs-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/tools/configtxgen/localconfig/config.go:276 +0x426
main.main()
        /w/workspace/fabric-release-jobs-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/tools/configtxgen/main.go:271 +0xce7
+ res=2
+ set +x
Failed to generate orderer genesis block...
```

Do I need to set the private key it mentions at the beginning `BYFN_CA1_PRIVATE_KEY variable is not set`? Or do I need to specify a channel name as I've seen in other posts?

I can't find a `configtx.yaml` file in the `/fabcar` folder but can fine one in `/fabric-samples/config'. I still get the same error. Here is the file (note I removed the headers to remain in the 30k character limit for StackOverflow)

```
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

---

Organizations:

    # SampleOrg defines an MSP using the sampleconfig. It should never be used
    # in production but may be used as a template for other definitions.
    - &SampleOrg
        # Name is the key by which this org will be referenced in channel
        # configuration transactions.
        # Name can include alphanumeric characters as well as dots and dashes.
        Name: SampleOrg

        # ID is the key by which this org's MSP definition will be referenced.
        # ID can include alphanumeric characters as well as dots and dashes.
        ID: SampleOrg

        # MSPDir is the filesystem path which contains the MSP configuration.
        MSPDir: msp

        # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
        # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
        #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
        Policies: &SampleOrgPolicies
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('SampleOrg.member')"
                # If your MSP is configured with the new NodeOUs, you might
                # want to use a more specific rule like the following:
                # Rule: "OR('SampleOrg.admin', 'SampleOrg.peer', 'SampleOrg.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('SampleOrg.member')"
                # If your MSP is configured with the new NodeOUs, you might
                # want to use a more specific rule like the following:
                # Rule: "OR('SampleOrg.admin', 'SampleOrg.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('SampleOrg.admin')"

        # OrdererEndpoints is a list of all orderers this org runs which clients
        # and peers may to connect to to push transactions and receive blocks respectively.
        OrdererEndpoints:
            - "127.0.0.1:7050"

        # AnchorPeers defines the location of peers which can be used for
        # cross-org gossip communication. Note, this value is only encoded in
        # the genesis block in the Application section context.
        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: 127.0.0.1
              Port: 7051


Capabilities:
    # Channel capabilities apply to both the orderers and the peers and must be
    # supported by both.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
        # V1.4.2 for Channel is a catchall flag for behavior which has been
        # determined to be desired for all orderers and peers running at the v1.4.2
        # level, but which would be incompatible with orderers and peers from
        # prior releases.
        # Prior to enabling V1.4.2 channel capabilities, ensure that all
        # orderers and peers on a channel are at v1.4.2 or later.
        V1_4_2: true

    # Orderer capabilities apply only to the orderers, and may be safely
    # used with prior release peers.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
        # V1.1 for Orderer is a catchall flag for behavior which has been
        # determined to be desired for all orderers running at the v1.1.x
        # level, but which would be incompatible with orderers from prior releases.
        # Prior to enabling V1.1 orderer capabilities, ensure that all
        # orderers on a channel are at v1.1.0 or later.
        V1_1: true

    # Application capabilities apply only to the peer network, and may be safely
    # used with prior release orderers.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
        # V1.4.2 for Application enables the new non-backwards compatible
        # features and fixes of fabric v1.4.2
        V1_4_2: true
        # V1.3 for Application enables the new non-backwards compatible
        # features and fixes of fabric v1.3.
        V1_3: false
        # V1.2 for Application enables the new non-backwards compatible
        # features and fixes of fabric v1.2 (note, this need not be set if
        # later version capabilities are set)
        V1_2: false
        # V1.1 for Application enables the new non-backwards compatible
        # features and fixes of fabric v1.1 (note, this need not be set if
        # later version capabilities are set).
        V1_1: false


Application: &ApplicationDefaults
    ACLs: &ACLsDefault
        # This section provides defaults for policies for various resources
        # in the system. These "resources" could be functions on system chaincodes
        # (e.g., "GetBlockByNumber" on the "qscc" system chaincode) or other resources
        # (e.g.,who can receive Block events). This section does NOT specify the resource's
        # definition or API, but just the ACL policy for it.
        #
        # User's can override these defaults with their own policy mapping by defining the
        # mapping under ACLs in their channel definition

        #---Lifecycle System Chaincode (lscc) function to policy mapping for access control---#

        # ACL policy for lscc's "getid" function
        lscc/ChaincodeExists: /Channel/Application/Readers

        # ACL policy for lscc's "getdepspec" function
        lscc/GetDeploymentSpec: /Channel/Application/Readers

        # ACL policy for lscc's "getccdata" function
        lscc/GetChaincodeData: /Channel/Application/Readers

        # ACL Policy for lscc's "getchaincodes" function
        lscc/GetInstantiatedChaincodes: /Channel/Application/Readers

        #---Query System Chaincode (qscc) function to policy mapping for access control---#

        # ACL policy for qscc's "GetChainInfo" function
        qscc/GetChainInfo: /Channel/Application/Readers

        # ACL policy for qscc's "GetBlockByNumber" function
        qscc/GetBlockByNumber: /Channel/Application/Readers

        # ACL policy for qscc's  "GetBlockByHash" function
        qscc/GetBlockByHash: /Channel/Application/Readers

        # ACL policy for qscc's "GetTransactionByID" function
        qscc/GetTransactionByID: /Channel/Application/Readers

        # ACL policy for qscc's "GetBlockByTxID" function
        qscc/GetBlockByTxID: /Channel/Application/Readers

        #---Configuration System Chaincode (cscc) function to policy mapping for access control---#

        # ACL policy for cscc's "GetConfigBlock" function
        cscc/GetConfigBlock: /Channel/Application/Readers

        # ACL policy for cscc's "GetConfigTree" function
        cscc/GetConfigTree: /Channel/Application/Readers

        # ACL policy for cscc's "SimulateConfigTreeUpdate" function
        cscc/SimulateConfigTreeUpdate: /Channel/Application/Readers

        #---Miscellanesous peer function to policy mapping for access control---#

        # ACL policy for invoking chaincodes on peer
        peer/Propose: /Channel/Application/Writers

        # ACL policy for chaincode to chaincode invocation
        peer/ChaincodeToChaincode: /Channel/Application/Readers

        #---Events resource to policy mapping for access control###---#

        # ACL policy for sending block events
        event/Block: /Channel/Application/Readers

        # ACL policy for sending filtered block events
        event/FilteredBlock: /Channel/Application/Readers

    # Organizations lists the orgs participating on the application side of the
    # network.
    Organizations:

    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Application policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/Application/<PolicyName>
    Policies: &ApplicationDefaultPolicies
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

    # Capabilities describes the application level capabilities, see the
    # dedicated Capabilities section elsewhere in this file for a full
    # description
    Capabilities:
        <<: *ApplicationCapabilities


Orderer: &OrdererDefaults

    # Orderer Type: The orderer implementation to start.
    # Available types are "solo" and "kafka".
    OrdererType: solo

    # Addresses used to be the list of orderer addresses that clients and peers
    # could connect to.  However, this does not allow clients to associate orderer
    # addresses and orderer organizations which can be useful for things such
    # as TLS validation.  The preferred way to specify orderer addresses is now
    # to include the OrdererEndpoints item in your org definition
    Addresses:
        # - 127.0.0.1:7050

    # Batch Timeout: The amount of time to wait before creating a batch.
    BatchTimeout: 2s

    # Batch Size: Controls the number of messages batched into a block.
    # The orderer views messages opaquely, but typically, messages may
    # be considered to be Fabric transactions.  The 'batch' is the group
    # of messages in the 'data' field of the block.  Blocks will be a few kb
    # larger than the batch size, when signatures, hashes, and other metadata
    # is applied.
    BatchSize:

        # Max Message Count: The maximum number of messages to permit in a
        # batch.  No block will contain more than this number of messages.
        MaxMessageCount: 500

        # Absolute Max Bytes: The absolute maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch. The maximum block size is this value
        # plus the size of the associated metadata (usually a few KB depending
        # upon the size of the signing identities). Any transaction larger than
        # this value will be rejected by ordering. If the "kafka" OrdererType is
        # selected, set 'message.max.bytes' and 'replica.fetch.max.bytes' on
        # the Kafka brokers to a value that is larger than this one.
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 10 MB

        # Preferred Max Bytes: The preferred maximum number of bytes allowed
        # for the serialized messages in a batch. Roughly, this field may be considered
        # the best effort maximum size of a batch. A batch will fill with messages
        # until this size is reached (or the max message count, or batch timeout is
        # exceeded).  If adding a new message to the batch would cause the batch to
        # exceed the preferred max bytes, then the current batch is closed and written
        # to a block, and a new batch containing the new message is created.  If a
        # message larger than the preferred max bytes is received, then its batch
        # will contain only that message.  Because messages may be larger than
        # preferred max bytes (up to AbsoluteMaxBytes), some batches may exceed
        # the preferred max bytes, but will always contain exactly one transaction.
        PreferredMaxBytes: 2 MB

    # Max Channels is the maximum number of channels to allow on the ordering
    # network. When set to 0, this implies no maximum number of channels.
    MaxChannels: 0

    Kafka:
        # Brokers: A list of Kafka brokers to which the orderer connects. Edit
        # this list to identify the brokers of the ordering service.
        # NOTE: Use IP:port notation.
        Brokers:
            - kafka0:9092
            - kafka1:9092
            - kafka2:9092

    # EtcdRaft defines configuration which must be set when the "etcdraft"
    # orderertype is chosen.
    EtcdRaft:
        # The set of Raft replicas for this network. For the etcd/raft-based
        # implementation, we expect every replica to also be an OSN. Therefore,
        # a subset of the host:port items enumerated in this list should be
        # replicated under the Orderer.Addresses key above.
        Consenters:
            - Host: raft0.example.com
              Port: 7050
              ClientTLSCert: path/to/ClientTLSCert0
              ServerTLSCert: path/to/ServerTLSCert0
            - Host: raft1.example.com
              Port: 7050
              ClientTLSCert: path/to/ClientTLSCert1
              ServerTLSCert: path/to/ServerTLSCert1
            - Host: raft2.example.com
              Port: 7050
              ClientTLSCert: path/to/ClientTLSCert2
              ServerTLSCert: path/to/ServerTLSCert2

        # Options to be specified for all the etcd/raft nodes. The values here
        # are the defaults for all new channels and can be modified on a
        # per-channel basis via configuration updates.
        Options:
            # TickInterval is the time interval between two Node.Tick invocations.
            TickInterval: 500ms

            # ElectionTick is the number of Node.Tick invocations that must pass
            # between elections. That is, if a follower does not receive any
            # message from the leader of current term before ElectionTick has
            # elapsed, it will become candidate and start an election.
            # ElectionTick must be greater than HeartbeatTick.
            ElectionTick: 10

            # HeartbeatTick is the number of Node.Tick invocations that must
            # pass between heartbeats. That is, a leader sends heartbeat
            # messages to maintain its leadership every HeartbeatTick ticks.
            HeartbeatTick: 1

            # MaxInflightBlocks limits the max number of in-flight append messages
            # during optimistic replication phase.
            MaxInflightBlocks: 5

            # SnapshotIntervalSize defines number of bytes per which a snapshot is taken
            SnapshotIntervalSize: 20 MB

    # Organizations lists the orgs participating on the orderer side of the
    # network.
    Organizations:

    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Orderer policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/Orderer/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        # BlockValidation specifies what signatures must be included in the block
        # from the orderer for the peer to validate it.
        BlockValidation:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"

    # Capabilities describes the orderer level capabilities, see the
    # dedicated Capabilities section elsewhere in this file for a full
    # description
    Capabilities:
        <<: *OrdererCapabilities


Channel: &ChannelDefaults
    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Channel policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        # Who may invoke the 'Deliver' API
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        # Who may invoke the 'Broadcast' API
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        # By default, who may modify elements at this config level
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"


    # Capabilities describes the channel level capabilities, see the
    # dedicated Capabilities section elsewhere in this file for a full
    # description
    Capabilities:
        <<: *ChannelCapabilities

################################################################################
#
#   PROFILES
#
#   Different configuration profiles may be encoded here to be specified as
#   parameters to the configtxgen tool. The profiles which specify consortiums
#   are to be used for generating the orderer genesis block. With the correct
#   consortium members defined in the orderer genesis block, channel creation
#   requests may be generated with only the org member names and a consortium
#   name.
#
################################################################################
Profiles:

    # SampleSingleMSPSolo defines a configuration which uses the Solo orderer,
    # and contains a single MSP definition (the MSP sampleconfig).
    # The Consortium SampleConsortium has only a single member, SampleOrg.
    SampleSingleMSPSolo:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *SampleOrg
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *SampleOrg

    # SampleSingleMSPKafka defines a configuration that differs from the
    # SampleSingleMSPSolo one only in that it uses the Kafka-based orderer.
    SampleSingleMSPKafka:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            OrdererType: kafka
            Organizations:
                - *SampleOrg
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *SampleOrg

    # SampleInsecureSolo defines a configuration which uses the Solo orderer,
    # contains no MSP definitions, and allows all transactions and channel
    # creation requests for the consortium SampleConsortium.
    SampleInsecureSolo:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:

    # SampleInsecureKafka defines a configuration that differs from the
    # SampleInsecureSolo one only in that it uses the Kafka-based orderer.
    SampleInsecureKafka:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Orderer:
            OrdererType: kafka
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:

    # SampleDevModeSolo defines a configuration which uses the Solo orderer,
    # contains the sample MSP as both orderer and consortium member, and
    # requires only basic membership for admin privileges. It also defines
    # an Application on the ordering system channel, which should usually
    # be avoided.
    SampleDevModeSolo:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - <<: *SampleOrg
                  Policies:
                      <<: *SampleOrgPolicies
                      Admins:
                          Type: Signature
                          Rule: "OR('SampleOrg.member')"
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - <<: *SampleOrg
                  Policies:
                      <<: *SampleOrgPolicies
                      Admins:
                          Type: Signature
                          Rule: "OR('SampleOrg.member')"
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - <<: *SampleOrg
                      Policies:
                          <<: *SampleOrgPolicies
                          Admins:
                              Type: Signature
                              Rule: "OR('SampleOrg.member')"

    # SampleDevModeKafka defines a configuration that differs from the
    # SampleDevModeSolo one only in that it uses the Kafka-based orderer.
    SampleDevModeKafka:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            OrdererType: kafka
            Organizations:
                - <<: *SampleOrg
                  Policies:
                      <<: *SampleOrgPolicies
                      Admins:
                          Type: Signature
                          Rule: "OR('SampleOrg.member')"
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - <<: *SampleOrg
                  Policies:
                      <<: *SampleOrgPolicies
                      Admins:
                          Type: Signature
                          Rule: "OR('SampleOrg.member')"
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - <<: *SampleOrg
                      Policies:
                          <<: *SampleOrgPolicies
                          Admins:
                              Type: Signature
                              Rule: "OR('SampleOrg.member')"

    # SampleSingleMSPChannel defines a channel with only the sample org as a
    # member. It is designed to be used in conjunction with SampleSingleMSPSolo
    # and SampleSingleMSPKafka orderer profiles.   Note, for channel creation
    # profiles, only the 'Application' section and consortium # name are
    # considered.
    SampleSingleMSPChannel:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *SampleOrg

    # SampleDevModeEtcdRaft defines a configuration that differs from the
    # SampleDevModeSolo one only in that it uses the etcd/raft-based orderer.
    SampleDevModeEtcdRaft:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            OrdererType: etcdraft
            Organizations:
                - <<: *SampleOrg
                  Policies:
                      <<: *SampleOrgPolicies
                      Admins:
                          Type: Signature
                          Rule: "OR('SampleOrg.member')"
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - <<: *SampleOrg
                  Policies:
                      <<: *SampleOrgPolicies
                      Admins:
                          Type: Signature
                          Rule: "OR('SampleOrg.member')"
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - <<: *SampleOrg
                      Policies:
                          <<: *SampleOrgPolicies
                          Admins:
                              Type: Signature
                              Rule: "OR('SampleOrg.member')"
```

Comment: seems like your configtx.yml file have some syntax or type error.Can you upload that too?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your `FABRIC_CFG_PATH` is set to the directory which contains `configtx.yaml`

Try running `echo $FABRIC_CFG_PATH` and if it doesnot point to the directory which contains configtx.yaml, you need to set it by the command `export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD` inside the directory where you have `configtx.yaml`

If this doesn't work then you have errors in `configtx.yaml` file. You need to post that in your question too.

Comment: I found a `configtx.yaml` file in another folder, specifcally `fabric-samples/config`. I still get the same error. In any case, I posted the `configtx.yaml` file

Comment: Did you set the path of ``FABRIC_CFG_PATH`` to ``<PATH_TO_YOUR_PROJECT_FOLDER>/fabric-sample/config`` ?

Comment: Yes I did. (Thinking it may be easier just to move to Linux)

Comment: Yes, Linux supports fabric well, so you might feel it easier on Linux.